# store image into hdf5 store?

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library, h5py

I need to store the RGB image data (96*96*3) into the HDF5 datastore, similar to the example shown[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/gvxKfjyVzsI) where train_data size:  (42000, 1, 28, 28). My image data dimension is like (image_num, 3, 96, 96).

Here is my code to store one image into the store.

```
test_data = np.zeros(( 1 ,3,96,96))

try:
    im = Image.open("/road8.jpg")
except:
    print "failed to load image: %s" %("/road8.jpg")

img = im.resize((96, 96), Image.BILINEAR)

test_data[0,:,:,:] = np.array(img).astype(np.float32) / 255 

with h5py.File(script_dir+"/test.h5", 'w') as f:
    f['data'] = test_data
    f.close()
```

However it gives me a error saying "could not broadcast input array from shape (96,96,3) into shape (3,96,96)", I know it means if I initialize the data like np.zeros(( 1 ,96,96, 3)), it will be ok. However I need to the order of the datastore has to be like np.zeros(( 1 ,3,96,96)). so the only way is to transform it after resize the image.

How would I do it?

---

I tried this solution

```
img = im.resize((96, 96))
img = np.transpose(img, (2,0,1))
```

but got a error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vehicle_hdf5.py", line 51, in <module>
    img = np.transpose(img, (2,0,1))
  File "/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 537, in transpose
    return transpose(axes)
  File "/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1936, in transpose
    return self._new(self.im.transpose(method))
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What does it mean ?

Comment: Which line gives you this error ?

Answer (score 1):

You could swap axes using np.swapaxes(im, 0, 2), but if you want to preserve the order "height before width", I suggest you use np.transpose as follows:

```
img = np.transpose(img, (2, 0, 1))
# first axis becomes third, second becomes first, third becomes second
```

Comment: Thanks, @M.Massias, it should be right with np.transpose(img,(2,0,1)) but I got a error updated in the post.

Comment: @user824624 what is the shape of img after im.resize ?